# Why is max{n,k}= Ө(n+k)

Tags: asymptotics

I saw this relationship in my exercise.
    max{n,k}= Ө(n+k)
Could somebody prove it?

Comment: Use the definitions. Be mindful of what $n$, $k$ mean here, and how the definition of $\Theta$ extends to two parameters. (Hint: it doesn't, really.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming n and k to be non-negative,
$n\leq n+k$ and $k\leq n+k$. Hence,$\max(n, k) \in \mathcal{O}(n+k)$.
Next, $n+k≤2\max(n,k)$. Hence, $\max(n,k)\in\mathcal{\Omega}(n+k)$.

Hence, we get that $\max(n,k)\in \mathcal{\Theta}(n+k)$.